# PI3 not connecting any input devices, no wifi, no Bluetooth only GUI showing up!

Tags: pi-3

**Hi, my RPI3 was working perfectly until I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` and mistakenly stopped the process by `CTRL+C`, then after a reboot the PI doesn't detect the same keyboard and mouse he was handling well 2 minutes before, the GUI shows up but the mouse cursor isn't moving and keyboard has no effect (both light up so there is voltage supplied) and even the GUI shows the Wifi isn't connected (was working well 2 minutes ago), bluetooth icon also is dimmed and sound icon showing `x`.**

So, I can't connect with Putty because there is no internet, I can't use keyboard or mouse, I only have access to the SD card by my PC.

**>>> *the Ethernet LED blinks green when connecting a LAN cable but I currently* *can't connect both my computer and PI with Ethernet because I only have one* <<<**

Why did that happen? How can I fix this problem?

> Please note: I have valuable data installed on my PI3 and formatting the SD card is too risky for me.

Comment: you already answered your first question in the first sentence ... `stopped the process by CTRL+C`

Comment: OMG what should I do now?? isn't there any way to fix that? I can't communicate with my PI!!! please tell me!!!

Comment: first, back up the SD card on your computer so that you do not lose any data ... then google `RPi crash recovery`

Comment: note: get another SD card for doing the recovery